# python executa mas não envia nada na saída

Tags: python

por algum motivo, esse código está rodando, aparece que executou mas não tem resultado nenhum, alguém pode me ajudar?

```
def tempo(horaEntrada, minutoEntrada, horaSaida, minutoSaida):

  horaEntrada = int(input("digite a hora de entrada "))
  minutoEntrada = int(input("digite o minuto da entrada "))
  horaSaida = int(input("digite a hora de saida "))
  minutoSaida = int(input("digite o minuto de saida "))


  horaTotal = (horaSaida - horaEntrada)
  minutoTotal = (minutoSaida + minutoEntrada)

  return horaTotal, minutoTotal

  if minutoTotal >= 60:
    minutoTotal = minutoTotal - 60


  print(f"o horario de permanencia foi de {horaTotal}:{minutoTotal}")

  if horaEntrada >= 24:
    print("erro, a hora digitada é inválida") 

  elif minutoEntrada >= 60:
    print("erro, os minutos são inválidos")

  elif horaSaida >= 24:
    print("erro, a hora digitada é inválida") 

  elif minutoSaida >= 60:
    print("erro, os minutos são inválidos")


  valorT = horaTotal * 7
  print(f"o valor total é R${valorT}")
```

Answer (score 2):

Código Python é interpretado pela indentação. Tudo que está abaixo de `return horaTotal, minutoTotal` está sendo considerado como dentro da função, porém não é executado porque ao chegar no comando `return`, a função acaba.

Comment: agora deu certo, obrigado!

Comment: -De nada amigo!

Answer (score -2):

Quando a função foi determinada fez alguns parametros como obrigatorios a serem passados, e logo quando entra na função solicita novamente isso pode acarretar a erros aleatórios também